# How to create rolling lfo effect

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, replication

I was just researching about Virus TI products and I came with this patch

At 0:21 there is a rolling lfo modulation. I was wondering if I want to create such effect in Logic with any synth, how can this be re-created ? I mean the rolling effect of the tail. Im currently working with u-he zebra synth but I cant reproduce that that.

Thank you!
G.

Comment: Do you mean him changing the rate of the LFO? That's all it sounds like to me... unless I'm not hearing something.

Answer (score 3):

Don't have zebra, but it sounds to me like a square-shaped LFO with the rate being modulated up to a very high rate and back, producing that effect where the two values that the LFO is oscillating between are changing so fast that they blend into one tone.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a sound like this can also be accomplished by having two LFO generators, and changing the frequency of one, or the other.  That is, change the frequency relative to each LFO, hence causing the sound waves to drift in and out of sync with each other.

That is my very humble opinion based on my limited understanding of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the lfo is going into the audible range.  I dont think many software synths are capable of doing this.  you may be able to with an fm synthesizer though.